# Shortest Path Dijkstra

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, sql, query

I would like to calculate the shortest path with dijkstra algorithm.

sample query
`SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false);`

I imported an osm map, it has proper network. The name of the table is `at_2po_4pgr`, colums are
`id, osm_id, osm_name, osm_meta, osm_source_id, osm_target_id, clazz, flags, source, target, km, kmh, cost, reverse_cost, x1, y1, x2, y2, geom_way`.

in result I would like to see the shortest path and streets name in a row where route was planning.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You already have a working sample query which just has to be adjusted to your column names.

Comment: yes I tried, but I dont know which cloumn fit into the query
Please help @underdark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You best start with the [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/), and especially look at the chapter, which explains how to write a [simple plpgsql wrapper function](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html) to return additional attributes such as street name for example.

A query might look like this then:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom, b.osm_name FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM at_2po_4pgr',
                30, 60, false, false) a LEFT JOIN at_2po_4pgr b ON (a.id2 = b.id);
```

You really just have to change a few table/attribute names.

Comment: How can I calculate the distance between A and B in km?? with sum() function?

Comment: I think you better ask this as a new question, but just before I gave an answer which might help you, too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/86102/800

Comment: I tried, I got this
`ERROR: column "pgr_dijkstra.seq" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8`

Query:
`SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, sum(cost) AS cost  FROM pgr_dijkstra('`