# Run Shortest Path Dijkstra with pgrouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I use PostgreSQL 9.5.3, PostGIS 2.2 and pgRouting 2.3.2.

I have  the same problem as [Shortest Path Dijkstra](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85892) because I use the same data with the same columns but when I put

```
 SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom, b.osm_name FROM pgr_dijkstra('

            SELECT id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     length::double precision AS cost
                    FROM at_2po_4pgr',
            30, 60, false, false) a LEFT JOIN at_2po_4pgr b ON (a.id2 = b.id);
```

into SQL window I got

> ERROR: column link "cost" is ambiguous

How do I change cost atrribute?

I made it using this code:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, di.cost, geom_way, osm_name  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom_way) as cost FROM aa_2po_4pgr',
23941, 24159, false, false  ) as di  JOIN aa_2po_4pgr  ON di.id2 = aa_2po_4pgr.id
```

Comment: change define which cost you want - a.cost probably

Comment: Yes. I know that, but which query do I have to use? I'm completly green here. I checked my data with pgrouting plugin on QGIS and every works fine. I'm sad that there is no small window in this plugin which shows queriers that was made in QGIS.

Comment: Ok, I made it by myself.

Comment: The problem is that you have cost in at_2po_4pgr a and b, so the optimiizer doesn't know which one you are referring to. If you put a.cost or b.cost in the select, the error will go away.